# Is keeping a reference to an URLSessionTask necessary?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I've reading several examples related to `URLSession` and `URLSessionTask` where code snippets were shown and/or the sample project was available to download. Examples were about the quite common scenario of requesting some info to a REST service by using `URLSessionDataTask`, most of them having classes similar to this:

```
var defaultSession: URLSession
var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?

override init() {
   let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
   self.defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: self.operationQueue)

   super.init()
}

func callService(with searchUrl: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) {
   dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: searchUrl, completionHandler: completion)
   dataTask?.resume()
}
```

I find that usually a reference to `dataTask` is kept but it is not used at any other place out of that func. Which would be the reasons to keep a reference to the `dataTask`?

Comment: You can use the reference to cancel/suspend it later

Answer (score 6):

There's no need to keep reference to a `URLSessionDataTask` instance if you simply want to execute the data task once. You can simply do `defaultSession.dataTask(with: searchUrl, completionHandler: completion).resume()`

However, keeping a reference to a `URLSessionDataTask` instance can be useful in case you want to suspend or cancel it before it finishes execution.

There also seems to be a typo in your `callService` method. The `withUrl` input parameter isn't used anywhere, but there's a reference to `searchUrl`, which isn't an input parameter, so I suppose you wanted to call the `URL` input parameter `searchUrl`.

```
func callService(with searchUrl: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) {
   defaultSession.dataTask(with: searchUrl, completionHandler: completion).resume()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, there is a typo in my code snippet, I just corrected it.

Comment: I just noticed something in your answer, I guess you meant "cancel an ongoing dataTask" instead of "cancel it before it executes".

Comment: @AppsDev yeah that was meant to be "cancel before it finishes execution", so I corrected it